# select clause with having max condition

Tags: sql, oracle

For my database table:

```
//table1
name
---------
john
mary
ali
```

in my table2

```
//table2
title
---------
 test1
 test2
 test3
```

in my table3

```
//table3
name      title
-----------------
 john      test1
 john      test2
 john      test3
 mary      test2
```

So my question is to find the title that been joined by name for most many times.

So my query is:

```
SELECT t2.title from table2 t2 inner join table3 t3 on
   t2.title = t3.title inner join table1 t1 on 
   t1.name = t3.name having max(....)
```

as i check for some websites. all they use for the having clause is for the numbers only, i can't find any example that suit for my question that need to count(*)

expected output:

```
//result
title
---------
test2
```

Answer (score 2):

Order by the count to get a list starting from the most common ttile

```
SELECT t2.title 
from table2 t2 
inner join table3 t3 on t2.title = t3.title 
inner join table1 t1 on t1.name = t3.name 
group by t2.title
order by count(*) desc
```

To get only the top result use

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT t2.title 
    from table2 t2 
    inner join table3 t3 on t2.title = t3.title 
    inner join table1 t1 on t1.name = t3.name 
    group by t2.title
    order by count(*) desc
) X
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: i wan the max only. not all title

Comment: i dont think this is a good solution isn't? can't we use the max clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(name) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY COUNT(NAME) DESC)
FROM table3
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: The OP asked for the title most used, not the name

Comment: Then just replace 'name' with 'title'.